# Экземпляр Activity. Правильно или неправильно

Tags: android, activity

Почему не желательно создавать экземпляр Activity (к примеру,

```
    MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
```

) для доступа к его методам из другого Activity или класса? Какие есть этому альтернативы?

Comment: Созданая через new активити не отображается на экране, соответственно у нее нет конекста, а вы конечно же захотите его использовать внутри второй активити,что повлечет за собой кучу багов. Просто вынесите методы которые вы хотите вызывать из разных мест в отдельный класс и используйте его.

Comment: Создание собственных экземпляров активити не предусмотрено системой. Точнее, создать вы сможете, но использовать по назначению - нет. Активити создает сама ОС и связано это с тем, что данный класс глубоко интегрирован в систему, завязан на жизненный цикл и контекст и тд.

Answer (score 1):

Достаточно сделать метод/переменную и т.п `static`

Comment: Это приведет к утечкам памяти